# String1 recebe o valor da string2, mas quando a string1 é embaralhada a string2 também é

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, lista

estou fazendo um jogo de truco que roda no terminal, sou meio iniciante.

```
from random import shuffle

numeros = ['4', '5', '6', '7', '10', '11', '12', '1', '2', '3']
naipes = ['ouro', 'espada', 'copas', 'paus']


def criarBaralho():
    baralho = []
    for naipe in naipes:
        for numero in numeros:
            carta = '{} {}'.format(numero, naipe)
            baralho.append(carta)
    print('baralho criado\n', baralho)

return baralho

def embaralhar(baralho):
    embBaralho = baralho
    shuffle(embBaralho)

    print('baralho original\n', baralho)
    print('baralho embaralhado\n', embBaralho)

return embBaralho

embaralhar(criarBaralho())
```

eu quero que a string `baralho[]` continue como deveria ser: `baralho['4 ouro', '5 ouro',...]`, mas ela está sendo embaralhada do mesmo jeito que a string `embBaralho[]`.

Answer (score -1):

Consegui! É só usar o `copy()`

```
def embaralhar(baralho):
    embBaralho = baralho.copy()
    shuffle(embBaralho)
```

Comment: Não tem **nada** a ver com herança. O que acontece é que ao fazer `embBaralho = baralho`, ambas as variáveis passam a apontar para a mesma lista, por isso que embaralhar uma acaba mudando a "outra" (que não é outra lista, é apenas outra referência para a mesma lista)